# Performance Issue after upgrading to Hibernate 5.0.2 - Tomcat Server start-up time increased

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-5.x

After upgrading Hibernate version from 4.3.9.Final to 5.0.2.Final, Tomcat Server start-up time has increased.

After debugging, I realized that hibernate takes too much time in adding mapping locations (*.hbm.xml files) in its metadata sources.

I have added mapping location in session factory using following code, and in my project there are around 1000 hbm.xml files.

```
<bean id="baseSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">300</prop>
            <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/ehcache.xml</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="mappingLocations">
            <list>
               <value>classpath*:com/*/**/*.hbm.xml</value>
            </list> 
    </property>
 </bean>
```

While starting tomcat server, I debugged and fournd that in method

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet
```

following for loop takes too much time to add all mapping locations in metadata sources object of configuration class.

```
if (this.mappingLocations != null) {
    // Register given Hibernate mapping definitions, contained in resource files.
    for (Resource resource : this.mappingLocations) {
        sfb.addInputStream(resource.getInputStream());
    }
}
```

Is there any solution to improve performance here? Anyone noticed such issue after upgrading to Hibernate-5?

Comment: For starters don't scan `com` package but be more specific, that way scanning is faster, but adding it shouldn't have changed that much and I would say that the main culprit is Hibernate doing more/additional things when adding the mappings.

Comment: I have given more specific path to scan, but scanning is not consuming much time. Most of the time is consumed by for-loop which I have mentioned in my question for adding mapping locations.

Comment: Then the issue is in hibernate as the adding is done by hibernate (the `addInputStream` is the call to the hibernate stuff). So I guess you have to figure out what changed between those versions... I know that the whole internal configuration mechanism was overhauled so it might have to do with that.

Comment: What kind of increase are we talking about here? Seconds? Minutes?

Comment: With hibernate-4, i was able to start tomcat server in approx 2 to 3 minutes, but now with hibernate-5 it takes around 7-8 minutes.

Comment: That's pretty significant indeed, for development deployments excruciating (but so is 2-3 minutes of deploy time if you ask me). But seeing that there are a 1000 mapping files, I'm not completely amazed that your particular epic application shows a performance difference in Hibernate 5; that's pretty excessive. Can something be done in that corner perhaps, to have less mapping files but the ones you do have are bigger?

Comment: I do not know what could be done in order to reduce number of mapping file(and yes I'm having both smaller and bigger mapping files). One way is using Annotations I guess, but I don`t know that will increase or decrease performance as of now. Still at this point converting code for such large number of mapping files will take significant time.

Comment: Seems worth it to report as a regression bug in any case. Having so many mapping files seems like a stress test that the Hibernate team might not have done themselves.

Comment: Perhaps you are seeing https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10170 ?  Do you use out-dated DTD urls?

Comment: I`m using http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd DTD url. Also I have created one jira https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10214 to address above issue. But till now there is not any update provided.